# ORDS - Modify base URL of returned links

Tags: oracle-ords, neuronesb

I am looking at implementing an API gateway in Neuron ESB that will, among other things, be relying on Oracle ORDS. I want to ensure that all requests are routed through the gateway, which will implement custom logic to determine whether or not a specific call is forwarded to ORDS.

When calling ORDS now, returned resource links point directly to the ORDS host, eg:

```
{
  "rel": "self",
  "href": "http://ordshost:8080/ords/test/testmodule/emp/"
}
```

In order to keep everything going through the gateway, I want to replace this with something like:

```
{
  "rel": "self",
  "href": "http://neuronesbhost:8080/ords/test/testmodule/emp/"
}
```

I am hoping there's a smarter way around this than intercepting every call going into ORDS and coding a string replace function, but I have no idea what that might be. Ideally I would like to have configured ORDS to return links with a different base URL, but that doesn't seem to be possible (or I can't figure how, and yes, I Googled). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ORDS uses the standard http header `Host` for building links. I'm not familiar with Neuron but if it can set the host value, ords will honor that.

[image]